# how create read more function like wordpress in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have no idea how wordpress use `<!--more-->` to seperate the post then create read more link.
any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look in the WP source, the function is located in `wp-includes/post-template.php` around line 200 in the `get_the_content` function

I wouldn't recommend just copying and pasting as it likely won't work, but you may get the logic behind it. WP uses a preg_match for the `<!--more -->` tag, then parses it if it exists..

```
$content = $pages[$page-1];
 if ( preg_match('/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $content, $matches) ) {
           $content = explode($matches[0], $content, 2);
          if ( !empty($matches[1]) && !empty($more_link_text) )
               $more_link_text = strip_tags(wp_kses_no_null(trim($matches[1])));

           $hasTeaser = true;
      } else {
// so on
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the word_limiter() function from the Text Helper included in CodeIgniter to shorted your post to a fixed number of words, then append the "read more" hyperlink to that text, and echo.

[Text Helper Reference](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html)